# What is the right way to handle link-only answers that refer to another StackOverflow question/answer?

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers

I know that link-only answers are strongly discouraged, but what about when the link in question is one to another answer or question of StackOverflow?

One reason why link-only answers are bad is because the link can break. This is far less likely to happen when it is referring back to StackOverflow. However, it is still annoying because you have to go to a different page in order to see the correct answer, so having more than just the link would be preferrable.

Should I leave a comment, asking the answerer to add some more info? Should I mark the question as a duplicate of the question that was linked to? Or should the answer be deleted?

Comment: Is the linked question a duplicate of the current one? Vote to close it as such. If not, I guess the same rules still apply - a link-only answer *on its own* isn't very valuable, it should at least provide some context and explain how it answers the question

Comment: Just because the link goes to another [main] resource, that doesn't mean that that resource won't also break in the future, e.g. because of deletion, which has been known to happen to certain questions every now and then... `:P` Or another example, questions and answers also get edited, so maybe the linked-post changes so much that it no longer applies as a valid answer anymore `:P`

Comment: Mods have a "convert to comment facility" for really useful links links. Otherwise delete.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I offer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24067885/103167) as an example of the right way to reuse an answer.

1. It applies the linked answer to the specifics of the local question.
2. The link text explains the different context of the linked-to answer. (why it isn't a duplicate)

---

[image: Example of reusing answer via link back to SO]

Comment: An answer within an answer. So meta. So Inception-esque.

Answer (score 13):

If the answer consists only of a link to another question or answer, either:

- it is a very bad answer, even "not an answer", and should be downvoted, flagged etc
- this question is a dupe of the link target

Some people don't know how to flag dupes so they do this. Follow their link, make a decision, come back and possibly flag/vote to close the question if it is a dupe, then take action on the answer.

If it's not a dupe, comment on the answer encouraging the answerer to provide more details and especially to explain why the answer to a different question is of any value here.