# What should I do with an answer that states the question is a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

What should I do, if anything, with an answer that clearly states the question is a duplicate, references the duplicate question and even quotes the answer to the duplicate?

I am talking of [this particular case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2101675/752842). I don't think i should flag it as "not an answer" because the post actually answers the question, although using the other post. Should this be flagged for moderator attention?

Comment: Yeah, it's a dupe. And although it answers the question, it doesn't add much at all beyond the quotation. Still, it's really old and has a number of upvotes, so I'm not particularly motivated to remove it.

Comment: On Meta.SE: [Should we flag answers that only contain a link to another Stack Overflow answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95491)

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [How to handle answers which copy its whole content from another answer with proper attribution?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285349)

Which...doesn't have an answer, so I can't make the riotously funny Meta joke answer that I wanted to. Voting to close. (See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258545/603977)

Comment: @JoshCaswell - Thanks, I couldn't find a duplicate. Although it would be nice if it had an answer. It feels weird to say it "solved my problem" since it doesn't have an answer.